# Fcm notifications received by android emulator and all ios devices but not on real android devices

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I developed a react native app, and the notifications were working fine up until I changed the API level to 31. The notifications are still received by my app when running in the android emulator but are not working on real android devices. I am receiving a success response from the function, but the notification is not received. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Here is my code that sends notifications.

```
    public bool RandomNotification(string fcmtoken, string content, string title, Dictionary<string, string> param, string type = "", string pagename = "")
    {
        WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        //serverKey - Key from Firebase cloud messaging server  
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", ""));
        //Sender Id - From firebase project setting  
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", ""));
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        var payload = new object();
        var soundname = "";
        var channelidname = "";
        if (type == "ref")
        {
            soundname = "arabian.wav";
            channelidname = "WaitList1";
        }
        else if (type == "wait")
        {
            soundname = "waitlist.wav";
            channelidname = "WaitList";
        }
        payload = new
        {
            to = fcmtoken,
            priority = "high",
            content_available = true,
            notification = new
            {
                body = content,
                title = title,
                badge = 1,
                sound = soundname,
                android_channel_id = channelidname
            },
            data = new
            {
                type = "random",
                pagename,
                param

            }

        };

        string postbody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload).ToString();
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postbody);
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (dataStreamResponse != null) using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                        {
                            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                            if (sResponseFromServer.Contains("\"success\":1")) {
                                label2.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(label2.Text) + 1).ToString();
                                return true;
                            }
                            //result.Response = sResponseFromServer;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check these things:

- You are asking notification permission.
- AndroidManifest file for release mode are filled correctly.
- You did give permission for receiving notifications.
- Make sure you are waiting some little time. It can take some minutes to receive notification.

If you are sure that all of these things are done correctly but still not receiving, run the app in release mode. But debug with prints in FCM inbuild onMessage methods.

Comment: It was working before I upgraded the minsdkversion to 31, so it is definitely not an issue of permissions. Where should log the prints? Since I am only having this problem when my app is shut down logging in the react code wont be useful.